# How do I `grep` through .xz compresses files?

Tags: grep, xz

I'm using Red Hat Virtualization ([RHV](https://access.redhat.com/products/red-hat-virtualization)) and it logs all of its files in this directory:

```
$ pwd
/var/log/vdsm

$ ls | column -c 80 | head -10
backup          vdsm.log.34.xz      vdsm.log.69.xz
import          vdsm.log.35.xz      vdsm.log.6.xz
mom.log         vdsm.log.36.xz      vdsm.log.70.xz
mom.log.1       vdsm.log.37.xz      vdsm.log.71.xz
mom.log.2       vdsm.log.38.xz      vdsm.log.72.xz
mom.log.3       vdsm.log.39.xz      vdsm.log.73.xz
mom.log.4       vdsm.log.3.xz       vdsm.log.74.xz
mom.log.5       vdsm.log.40.xz      vdsm.log.75.xz
supervdsm.log   vdsm.log.41.xz      vdsm.log.76.xz
upgrade.log     vdsm.log.42.xz      vdsm.log.77.xz
```

I've used the `z*` tools such as `zgrep` & `zcat` to look through `.gz` & `.Z` files but it doesn't appear to deal with `.xz` compression.

What's an easy way to `grep` through a directory of `.xz` files?

Comment: Would it be fair to add a RHEL tag, since the OS (and answer) utilize RPM?

Comment: I don’t think so, the conclusion of the answer is valid on other platforms too (the package providing `xz` in Debian has the same helpers). RPM isn’t RHEL-specific either.

Comment: Same sentiment as @StephenKitt's.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look through the tooling provided by the `xz` RPM on RHEL/CentOS/Fedora distros this RPM includes a few helper wrapper scripts that you can enlist to make short work of this.

#### Identifying a Lead

With issues such as this I typically start by locating the RPMs that provide the tooling. In this case `xz` is the compression CLI so let's locate it and see what RPM provides it:

```
$ type -f xz
xz is /usr/bin/xz

$ rpm -qf /usr/bin/xz
xz-5.2.2-1.el7.x86_64
```

Now let's look and see if it provides anything with the name `grep` in it:

```
$ rpm -ql xz | grep -E 'bin/.*grep'
/usr/bin/xzegrep
/usr/bin/xzfgrep
/usr/bin/xzgrep
```

It does. So let's try using `xzgrep` since that's what we're after in terms of functionality:

```
$ xzgrep -l ocp-app-01c *
mom.log.4
vdsm.log.2.xz
vdsm.log.81.xz
```

**NOTE:** Above we're looking for occurrences of `ocp-app-01c` and printing files that contain it.

#### Usage

The usage is identical to `grep`:

```
$ xzgrep --help
Usage: xzgrep [OPTION]... [-e] PATTERN [FILE]...
Look for instances of PATTERN in the input FILEs, using their
uncompressed contents if they are compressed.

OPTIONs are the same as for 'grep'.

Report bugs to <lasse.collin@tukaani.org>.
```